# Regexp не выбирает 1 символ

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения, typescript

Регулярное выражение: `/[^ ][\S \r\n]*[^ ]/` не выбирает символ если он был один в строке.

Регулярное выражение удовлетворяет потребностям. но по какой то причине не выбирает 1 символ или букву или цифру.

```js
const reg = /[^ ][\S \r\n]*[^ ]/

console.log("Name".match(reg))

console.log("   Name    sss".match(reg))
console.log("   777 777 Name    sss".match(reg))
console.log("  7".match(reg))

// Это не показывается а должно :

console.log("  s".match(reg), "s") // s
console.log(" s     ".match(reg), "s")  // s
```

Пример:

`q` - не выберет а должен

`q` - не выберет а должен

`q  q`       выберет учасаток `q  q`

Задача regexp получить масив содержащий отфильтрованную строку в индексе 0

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: `    q  q      выберет учасаток q  q` это логично, т.к. `[^ ]` это говорит, что нужен любой символ, кроме пробела, а тут `[\S \r\n]*` что найти пробельные символы, если есть. Т.е. ваша регулярка захватит от 2 символов, и они не должны быть пробелами, поэтому и `q`, ` q` не захватываются

Comment: А в чем суть задачи? Напишите в вопросе что должна искать регулярка с примером данных и ожидаемым результатом

Comment: Может тебе подойдет это регулярное выражение:```/\s(?!\S)/g```

Comment: Locker дополнил мой вопрос примерами. Да, моя задача избавиться от крайних пробелов... тоесть удалять пробелы с самого начала и в самом конце. колличество пробелов в центре (между символов, слов и тд.) не важно. оди должны быть выбраны. Загвоздка только в том что  1 символ не выбирается а для меня это критично.

Comment: `/\s(?!\S)/g` к сожалени. не подходит в моем случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно `/\S+(?:\s*\S+)*/` подойти. Т.е. берется непробельная последовательность и к ней неограниченное число раз может дописываться пробельно-непробельная последовательность.

```js
const reg = /\S+(?:\s*\S+)*/

console.log("Name".match(reg))

console.log("   Name    sss".match(reg))
console.log("   777 777 Name    sss".match(reg))
console.log("  7".match(reg))

// Это не показывается а должно :

console.log("  s".match(reg), "s") // s
console.log(" s     ".match(reg), "s")  // s
```

Comment: Благодарю, это именно то что нужно